# Cookie will not set/output to future page

Tags: php, ajax, cookies

I cannot get the cookie to output on the page 'images.php'. I have got cookies working in other areas of my site but I cannot get it to work here. My form uses an AJAX submit which passes the data to a PHP file and then if there are no errors in that file redirects the user to the next step in the process.

HTML Input field

```
<input type="text" name="price" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter the price you wish to list your item for" />
```

AJAX Submit

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('form.ajax').on('submit', function () {
    var that= $(this),
        url = 'inc/admin/validate_sell.php',
        type = that.attr('method'),
        data = {};
    that.find('[name]').each(function(index, value) {
        var that = $(this),
            name = that.attr('name'),
            value = that.val();

        data[name] = value;
    });
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: type,
        data: data,
        success: function(data) {
            $("#responce").html(data);  

        }
    });
    return false;   
});
</script>
```

PHP

```
setcookie('price', $_POST['price'], time()+3600);
echo '<script>window.location.replace("http://localhost/ur/images.php")</script>';
```

Future page which cookies should be echoed out on (images.php).

```
<?php echo $_COOKIE['price']; ?>
```

However this returns no value on 'images.php'.

Comment: Try adding the path parameter. `setcookie('price', $_POST['price'], time()+3600, "/");` You could also add the domain parameter too if this is on a live webserver vs. running localhost